# android reverse geocoding service not found exception on emulator 2.3.3

Tags: android

I am Currently using android emulator 2.3.3 . i want to get the location from coordinates. but i am getting this "service not available" exception. 
here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
        if (e.getAction() == 1) {
            GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(GoogleMaps.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = coder.getFromLocation(
                        point.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                        point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                String address = "";
                Address a = addresses.get(0);
                Toast.makeText(GoogleMaps.this, a.getCountryName(), 300).show();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(GoogleMaps.this, e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        return false;
```

Comment: What is your exact "Target" in your avd (should be Google APIs(...) - API Level 10)

Comment: Have you added the required permissions in your manifest file ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Is the emulator set up to use "Android 2.3.3" or "Google APIs" 2.3.3?

Comment: My Target Emulator is Google Api. and i already added those two permissions but its not working. i am beating up my mind for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago, and I discovered that indeed there is such a problem for the emulators with Android 2.3.3. I could find a better solution than to use another emulator with different Android version.